# unable to access scope property value in directive from a listener function of dragover event inside the link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive "droppable" and in scope I have a property called "configuration" which contains the value of type object. This is being bind with the individual object inside the ng-repeater.

I have added an event listener & handler for "dragover" event of element inside link function. In the handler of this element I am accessing the scope.configuration which should contain the value I have provided for it from my html template(value is a object inside ng-repeater).

The template I have created is a recursive one so the dragOver event is bind to elements and their children as well.

what I am doing with all these is whenever you drag something over these elements depending upon the configuration object(which is an array of values which decide whether this is the droppable area)user is indicated by setting .dropEffect=move / none.

The problem is I am not getting the scope.configuration for the target element of "dragOver: event. Please help me with this.

```
comDir.directive('droppable', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            "configuration": "=config",
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            var el = element[0];
            el.dataset.isDroppable = true;


            var fnDragOver = function (e) {

                var targetEl = e.target;

                // no action if element doesn't have droppable attribute.
                if(!targetEl.hasAttribute('droppable'))
                    return false;

                var el_isDroppable = targetEl.getAttribute('droppable') === "false"? false: true;
                var indx;
                //checking if the draggedOperation is in allowedDrops of configuration object
                if(scope.configuration){
                    indx = scope.configuration.allowedDrops.indexOf(scope.$parent.draggedOperation);
                };

                if(el_isDroppable && (!scope.configuration || indx >= 0) ) {
                    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';                            

                    if(el_isDroppable)
                        $(targetEl).addClass('borderRed');

                    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

                    scope.onDragover();
                    return false;
                }else{
                    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'none';
                }

            };
                    //,true);

            var removeListeners = function(){
                el.removeEventListener("dragover", fnDragOver);
            };
            var addListeners = function(){
                el.addEventListener("dragover", fnDragOver, false);
            };

            attrs.$observe("droppable", function (value) {
                if(value == "false"){
                    removeListeners();
                }else{
                    addListeners();
                }
            });


        }
    };
});
```